# Android Kitkat 4.4 no volume button

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, locked-out

I forgot my password on the Android Kitkat 4.4 tablet how do I unlock the device? There is no volume button, only power and home button.

Comment: For a starter, please check with our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info). Also consider checking [questions using this tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locked-out).